# An easier way of referring to the index of a desired dictionary (Python)?

Tags: python, for-loop

Question feels like it's phrased poorly, feel free to adjust it if you agree and know how better to phrase it.

I have the following code:

```
def owned_calendars(cal_items):
    """Returns only the calendars in which the user is marked as "owner"

    """
    owner_cals = []
    for entry in cal_items:
        if entry['accessRole'] == "owner":
            owner_cals.append(cal_items[cal_items.index(entry)])

    return owner_cals
```

`cal_items` is a `list` of `dictionaries`

In the line where I have written `owner_cals.append(cal_items[cal_items.index(entry)])` I'm trying to append the dictionaries that have the property `accessRole = owner`.

The line just seems super long and clunky, and I'm wondering if there's an easier/more intuitive way to do it?

Comment: What is wrong with `owner_cals.append(entry)`

Comment: Huh you're right. I didn't even think of that for some reason.. Nesting loops and dictionaries confuses me.

At first I tried `owner_cals.append(cal_items[entry])` and when that didn't work I ended up with what I have in the question

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this. You can do this in one line using [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions).

```
owner_cals = [x for x in cal_items if x["access_role"]=="owner"]
```

You can also use [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate) method.

```
owner_cals = [j for i,j in enumerate(cal_items) if j["access_role"]=="owner"]
```

**Also, remember `.index()` returns the lowest index where item is found**.

`["foo", "bar", "baz", "bar"].index("bar")` will always return 1.

Comment: I like list comprehension, however I find that it makes code harder to read for me later on. I'll try to get used to it a bit more though.

Comment: It might take a little time getting used to list comprehensions but it can be very useful. Do spend some time learning and mastering it. It will prove very helpful later.. :)